# Hidding annotations in MuPdf android

Tags: android, annotations, visibility, show-hide, mupdf

I am using the [MuPdf library](http://www.mupdf.com/) in an Android application. I am drawing annotations on a PDF but I want to show the option to toggle the visibility of all annotations on the current page.

I do not want to permanently erase anything.

Is it possible in this library? Please help.

Comment: Did you find any solution?